# Undefined offset: 0 i

Tags: php

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.success (:392:47)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

```
<?php
require_once("4_Utils/Utils.php");

class CapaDatos{
    public static $_db;
    public $_datos;

    public function __construct(){
        //si ya esta abierta la conexion no abrirla nuevamente
        if(!self::$_db ) {
                self::$_db=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gestionelo");
                self::$_db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            }  
        public function execute_array($sqlGroup, $sqlName, $arrFiltros, $modo){
        if ( ! session_id() ) session_start();
        //Leer archivo donde se encuentran los SQL a ejecutar
        $strSQL = "";
                $xml= simplexml_load_file(__DIR__."\\".$sqlGroup.".xml");
        $sqls = $xml->xpath("//SQL[@id='".$sqlName."']");
        $strSQL = $sqls[0]; 

                if ($strSQL =="" or $strSQL == null)
                {
                  utils_debugfile( "SQL No encontrado", $sqlGroup."-->".$sqlName);  
                };

                //Reemplazar variables globales del usuario
                if (isset($_SESSION['Email']))
                {
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@Email' , $_SESSION['Email'], $strSQL );
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@IdUserNet' , $_SESSION['IdUserNet'], $strSQL );
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@IdEmpresa' , $_SESSION['IdEmpresa'], $strSQL );
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@IdUsuario' , $_SESSION['IdUsuario'], $strSQL );
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@Alias' , $_SESSION['Alias'], $strSQL );
                    $strSQL = str_replace ( '@@NivelAdmin' , $_SESSION['NivelAdmin'], $strSQL );
                }                

                //Reemplazar parámetros
        foreach ($arrFiltros as $variable)  //=> $valor
        {
                        utils_debugfile( "CapaDatosId", $variable->Id);
                        utils_debugfile( "CapaDatosValue", $variable->Value);
            //$strSQL = str_replace ( '@'.$variable , $valor_formateado, $strSQL );
                        $strSQL = str_replace ( '@'.$variable->Id , $variable->Value, $strSQL );
        };

                //log ultimo sql ejecutado
                utils_debugfile( "SQL traducido->", $strSQL);
$_resultado=array
            (
                "estado" => -1,
                "mensaje" => "(sin mensaje)",
                "detalle" => "",
                "info" => "",
                "datos" => array()
            );
            //Ejecutar SQL
        $consulta= self::$_db->query($strSQL);   
        if (!$consulta)
        {
             $_resultado["estado"] = 0;
             $_resultado["mensaje"] = "Error en la ejecución de la consulta ";
             $_resultado["detalle"] =  $strSQL;
             $_resultado["info"] =  "";
             $_resultado["datos"][] =  array();

        }
        else
        {
             $_resultado["estado"] = 1;
             $_resultado["mensaje"] = "Ok";
             $_resultado["detalle"] =  "";
             $_resultado["info"] =  "";
                         if ($modo == "Consulta")
                         {
                                        while($filas=$consulta->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                     $_resultado["datos"][] = $filas;
                    }
                         }
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa tu pregunta. El error que planteas hace referencia a jquery, pero el codigo que publicas es de PHP. Cual es el problema? php da mal los datos, o jquery no lo interpreta correctamente?

Comment: Si se espera un JSON, en el servidor no puede haber absolutamente ninguna salida por pantalla que no sea un JSON. Ningún `echo`, ningún `print`, ningún texto HTML... nada de nada. Debes revisar que eso no ocurra, ni en tu código actual, ni en los archivos que agregas con `require` ni en funciones como `utils_debugfile`. En el código que compartes no se ve siquiera en qué parte devuelves las respuesta a Ajax. Y en el mensaje de error parece que intentas hacer `parse` de la respuesta, ¿por qué, si la respuesta ya es (o debería ser) un JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo una petición ajax desde el front. jQuery está esperando recibir JSON.

El backend devuelve *algo* que empieza con `<` lo cual no es un JSON válido. Lo más probable es que sea una respuesta de tipo HTML, como por ejemplo un Error 500.

Revisa en Chrome Devtools (o en Firefox) la petición ajax y su respuesta. En ésta debiese estar el mensaje de error.